# Regex - Get these but not these

Tags: regex, .htaccess

So I would like a regex which works like this:

Get [a-z0-9.-] but NOT 'example', 'example1', 'example3','user','home','h3llo'

**EDIT**

I need this regex in .htaccess

Examples can be anything like those what I wan to get.

Comment: Maybe possible with negative lookahead, depending on your language/regex variant. But why not just add checks for your exceptions after the regex check in the code that invokes the regex?

Comment: @CIRK you've asked two regex questions in the past 4 minutes. Maybe you should just learn regular expressions?

Comment: @CIRK http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is an excellent site to learn from.

Comment: @aschepler I need it in `.htaccess` , @Rafe Kettler I'm learning it, but I don't know how to exclude something from a regex, and I didn't really find anything about it. @marcog thanks very much!

Comment: @CIRK Have you tried the regular expression I gave in a `.htaccess` file? Chances are it works without any modification. It most likely supports negative lookahead.

Comment: @CIRK See my answer involving the RewriteCond directive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to give more examples of what you want matched, but this is a start: `^(?!example[13]?)[a-z0-9.-]+$`

```
>>> 'Match' if re.match('(?!example[13]?)[a-z0-9.-]', 'example') else 'No match'
'No match'
>>> 'Match' if re.match('(?!example[13]?)[a-z0-9.-]', 'example1') else 'No match'
'No match'
>>> 'Match' if re.match('(?!example[13]?)[a-z0-9.-]', 'example3') else 'No match'
'No match'
>>> 'Match' if re.match('(?!example[13]?)[a-z0-9.-]', 'dsfhdsagfir') else 'No match'
'Match'
```

It uses [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to fail on the strings you don't want to match.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I have some problems here getting the `[a-z0-9.-]` out from the regex, I tried $1 but that gives me `index.php` $2 doesn't works hmm :D But I hope I will fix it.

Comment: @CIRK We're here to help you, but without more information of your problem it's nigh impossible to help you more than we have.

Comment: This is how it looks right now in my htaccess file: `RewriteRule ^(?!user?)([a-z0-9.-]+)+(\/)?$ index.php?page=$1`

Comment: So If I go to `http://localhost/hellomarcog/` I want to get hellomarcog in the `$1` but if I go to `http://localhost/user/` I want to do nothing in this RewriteRule :) Because other RewriteRule is handling the special pages :) , I hope it's clear now.

Comment: @CIRK This is getting specific to .htaccess, perhaps ask another question describing as you've done to me? And tag it .htaccess.

Comment: Yes I know :D That's why I sayed I will fix it, but your answer is great, so I accept it ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about a [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)?  I assume this is for mod_rewrite since you're using an .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    !^(example[13]?|user|home|h3llo)$
  RewriteRule   ^([a-z0-9.-]+)$   <make-your-rewrite-using-$1-here>
</IfModule>
```

[untested]

Comment: Does this ignores those variables from the URL? Just because I need them but because they redirect the user somewhere else :)

Comment: Read the documentation on RewriteCond.  What this rule here says is that no rewrites will happen if REQUEST_URI is example1, example3, user, home, or h3llo.

Comment: Not a bad idea if I would like to ignore them, but I don't want to ignore them, I just have other RewriteRules for those words, however thanks very much for your answer, I didn't even know that this is possible, I'm very new in `.htaccess`!

Comment: You can always use one RewriteCond/RewriteRule pair for the special cases, and then another RewriteCond/RewriteRule pair for the general case.  You can also "stack" RewriteCond's.  I'd recommend giving the mod_rewrite documentation a quick read through if you're unsure about it.